# Bogus SQL Server (XTP) in-memory error 41842 claiming 4B rows updated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, memory-optimized-tables, in-memory-database

We run a large, very active set of in-memory (schema-only) tables - the main table has been split (sharded) into 5 separate databases because the table is a total size of > 50gb (Standard Edition limits the total size of in-memory tables to 32gb per database). The largest of the databases contains a 10gb table with roughly 1.5M rows.

The tables take 10K or so updates per minute, each of which updates between 500-10K rows. Tables are read from ~1K times per minute, returning between 50 and 1K rows.

Anonymized Schema:

[image: table schema screenshot]

Indexes:

[image: indexes screenshot]

There are 4 of these servers. About once a week, one of the servers stops accepting updates and instead returns this message (error Msg 41842): "Too many rows inserted or updated in this transaction. You can insert or update at most 4,294,967,294 rows in memory-optimized tables in a single transaction." That's just not a possible number, so we appear to be hitting some other condition that is triggering this message. When it happens, the server rejects all data changes and we have to reboot and refill the schema-only tables.

Servers are running on 12 CPUs w 128G memory (125G for sql)

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU11) (KB5003249) - 15.0.4138.2 (X64) May 27 2021 17:34:14 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Has anyone else seen this error?

Comment: Can you share the anonymized table schema including indexes?

Comment: Yep - added the schema and indexes to the original post

Comment: Do you know which statement causes this error? Can it be that an in-memory table type is filled instead?

Comment: ooh that's an interesting suggestion. Looking at the code...

Comment: Specifically in response to your question: I don't know which statement is throwing the error, but I know which proc it is. It's a pair of procedures, an outer that accepts an input parameter of changes, then it calls a corresponding input proc in the appropriate shard - one of the related databases, where it executes an inner proc.

Comment: So the inner proc accepts an input or a single in-memory table-valued parameter ... that can be anything from 1000 to 15K rows, usually, maybe twice that size max I think. I'm nearly positive that we can't create a dataset for insert that's > 4B rows.

The code we're executing is all native from that point. There's a "delete table" that accepts a 3-column key input of rows to delete, then iterates the table to delete all rows based on the keys. 

Then there's a single insert to the main table from the TVP based on "operation = 'U'"

I'm still examining the outer proc.

Comment: Hmm nope, we execute the call in the shard databases directly from the application - there's no nesting.

Comment: Normally I would set up Extended events (error_reported) and grab tsql stack to find the precise statement that generates the error. But I'm not sure if it works with IMOLTP as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128676/discussion-between-davids-and-zikato).